# Can we configure timeout for publishing message to SNS Topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, amazon-sns

I am using following:

```
final PublishRequest publishRequest =
                    new PublishRequest().withMessageAttributes(headers).withMessage(message)
                            .withTopicArn(vmsTopicArn);

            amazonSNS.publish(publishRequest);
```

AmazonSNS version is 1.11 "package com.amazonaws.services.sns". I want to know if there is a possibility to set timeout ? Do i have to configure somewhere in AmazonSNSClientBuilder

Comment: What would you want the 'timeout' to do?

Comment: If SNS is not available then give up after trying for this amount of time